# Escaping variables for dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on creating reports for user products. Since the reports are user specific I've tried dabbling into dynamic SQL to add columns that each user may need.

```
SET @oldpID = @pproduct
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #temp ( ID, compID, ['+ @sname +'])
VALUES ('+ @pproduct +', '+ @pcompanyid +', '+ @pscreference +')'


execute(@sql)
```

The problem is when I try to populate the information for the column `@sname` with the variable `@pscreference`. Since its user entered and may contain brackets and spaces, it breaks. I've tried using `QUOTESTRING()` and looked at some other questions but they were more so focused on sql-injections.

What would be the best way to escape it?

Comment: prepare a statement with placeholders, and then execute it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848808.aspx

Comment: `@pscreference` can contain brackets and spaces or anything else (except unescaped `'`) - you are just not quoting it in your `values` string

Comment: Doesn't the `'+`  `+'`around it count as quotes?

Comment: No, you need literal quotes; `+', '''+ @pscreference +''')'` - print `@sql` to see

Comment: Your a lifesaver! Thank you so much. :)